# Analogous service to CloudKit CKSubscription in Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: cloudkit, google-cloud-datastore, cksubscription

I've been learning about CloudKit in general and its `CKSubscription`s in particular. Since CloudKit and Google Cloud DataStore seem to share many similarities I am wondering this:

Is there an analogous service to `CKSubscription` available for Google Cloud Datastore, i.e. can I submit a subscription (along with a query) to the server once and have it push notifications about changes to me instead of pulling for changes with repeated fetches (with that same query)?

Answer (score 1):

I think that 'Google Cloud Pub/Sub' Is the closest that you can get for this. For more information see https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/overview

Comment: IMO this will take care of the transport part but one would still have to add functionality on the server to let subscriptions "fire" when entities in the Datastore change. In the case of iOS clients Apple's own push notifications could then serve as well, because there is a server-side API. If it's Android clients (or both), Google Clould Pub/Sub could help.